# $\forall\ x,y\in [a,b], |f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$ implies that the limit exists...

Tags: calculus, limits, contraction-operator

Let $f: [a,b]\to [a,b]$ be continuous, and satisfy
$\forall\ x\neq y\in [a,b], |f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$.

For any $x_0\in [a,b], x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\xi$, where $\xi$ is the unique fixed point of $f$: $f(\xi)=\xi$.

My attempt: Consider $y_n=|x_n-\xi|$, then $y_n\searrow, \geq 0$. So $\lim y_n=l\geq 0$ exists. If $l=0$, then we are done.

But I could not derive a contradiction when $l>0$. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: A much more general version of this (for compact metric spaces ) has been answered many times on this site.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Where? I know the unique fixed point proof. But how to show the Picard iteration converges?

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1472381/42969.